# How do I correct a parse error in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Every time I do a variable formula I get # error and it says `parse errors`

In iPad, I enter the formula `(= A2:-:B2)` and I keep getting a parse error in Google Sheets

Comment: Hi Breanna. Please give us more context to help you out.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve with formula = A2:-:B2 ? do you want to count difference?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `= A2:-:B2` try `=A2-B2` if you want to subtract B2 from A2

if you want to do it with ranges try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A-B2:B)`